# How to deserialized with java, Serialization with MongoDB C# Driver?

Tags: java, c#, mongodb

How to deserialized with java, Serialization with MongoDB C# Driver?

deserialized with c#:

BsonDocument bsonDocument1 = BsonSerializer.Deserialize(byteArray);

How to deserialized with Java ?

Thanks